# GRE related rates problem

Tags: calculus, related-rates

$\textbf{Problem}:$ A square pyramid of side length $100$cm and height of $100$cm is melting at a consistent rate such that all of the ice less than $y$ cm from the surface melts after $y$ hours. (Note the bottom is also melting). What is the rate of change of the volume, when the height is $10$ cm?

So I know $V=s^2\frac{h}{3}$ and the side length equals the height so can I set $s=h$? Then differentiate. I am confused on the rate of decrease of the surface area and how it relates.

Comment: Yes, set $s=h$ and differentiate.

Comment: A rule of thumb when solving related rate problems is to make all variables involved depend on time, differentiate everything using the chain rule, and seeing what happens.